# Splitting a string into smaller strings using split()

Tags: python, string, split

I'm trying to write a D&D dice roller program in Python.  I'd like to have the input be typed in the form "xdy+z" (ex. 4d6+12, meaning roll 4 6-sided di and add 12 to the result), and have the program "roll the dice", add the modifier, and output the result.  I'm trying to figure out how to split the string into numbers so I can have the program do the math.

I know of the split() function, and I'm trying to use it.  When I input the example above, I get the string [4 6 12], but when I have the program print string[1], I get a white space because it's still one full string.  I'd either like to figure out how to get the program to identify the individual numbers in the string, or a way to split the full string into smaller strings (like string1 = [4], string2 = [6], string3 = [12]).

Yes, I tried Google and searching this site, but I'm not sure what the terminology for this type of process is to it's been hard to find help.

Here's the relevant code:

```
separators = ["d", "+", "-"]
for sep in separators:
     inputText = inputText.replace(sep, ' ')
```

Comment: You say you know of the `split` function yet you don't use it. Moreover, the `dice` module does exactly this.

Comment: I mentioned the split function because the other people who asked about similar topics were told "just use split()" and got no real help.  I left the code in this form because the end result is the same as using split

Comment: That's because it's the answer. `inputText.split()` gives exactly what you want.

Comment: It gives one string with all three numbers.  I want three different strings with one number each.  Henry Woody's answer is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for this instead of splitting the string up. Just capture each numeric position with a group. Check out the docs on the [`re` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for details.

Here's a sample:

```
import re

pattern = r"(?P<rolls>\d+)d(?P<sides>\d+)\+(?P<add>\d+)"
match = re.match(pattern, input_text)
rolls = int(match["rolls"])
sides = int(match["sides"])
add = int(match["add"])
```

With `input_text` as "4d6+12" as in your example, the resulting values are:

```
print(rolls) # 4
print(sides) # 6
print(add) # 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution without regular expressions, using `find`, slicing and `split`. First, find the position of `+` or `-` to get the last number. Then, split the rest at `d`. Also, convert the partial strings to `int`:

```
s = "4d6+12"

if "-" in s:
    pos = s.find("-")
    add = int(s[pos:])
elif "+" in s:
    pos = s.find("+")
    add = int(s[pos:])
else:
    add = 0
    pos = len(s)

rolls, sides = map(int, s[:pos].split("d"))

print(f"{rolls=} {sides=} {add=}")
```